# am getting a reference Error : event is not defined onEdit I do not understand why I am getting this error>?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pull from one sheet to the next sheet.

```
function onEdit(event) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
      var r = event.source.getActiveRange();`enter code here`
    
      if(s.getName() == "Main" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == "Chair") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Chair");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
      }
    }
```

The code above comes from this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/scottsommer22/27ef99e76d9258aa6c51d04dd62897c9) from [scottsommer22](https://gist.github.com/scottsommer22).

Answer (score 1):

Do not run the function in the script editor. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet, and the `event` object will then be filled in the way the function needs. See [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Answer (score 1):

According to an answer from [Google Apps onEdit Event - event.source is undefined for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284061/google-apps-onedit-event-event-source-is-undefined-for?answertab=votes#tab-top), these built-in simple event handlers need the context of the event to be passed in in order to work properly. If you run them from the Script Editor directly, then no event object is passed in, which is why you get the error.

If you want to run and test your code on the script editor and at the same time be able to use the onEdit trigger, you can edit your script to something like this:

```
function onEdit() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
    
      if(s.getName() == "Main" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == "Chair") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Chair");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
      }
    }
```